# Join list of lists by one of the list items

Tags: elixir

I have this list of lists structure:

```
[
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-25wv5", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-2nhbs", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-5b4dw", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-p7sx9", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],          
  ["coredns-autoscaler-76f8869cc9-gd69j", "kube-system", "worker-1", "1", "5"],
  ["coredns-55b58f978-q2skn", "kube-system", "worker-1", "7", "11"] 
]
```

And I want to merge them by the second list item (nginx-deployment, kube-system, etc) and sum the two latest items and remove the first item.

So it would look like this:

```
[
  ["nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "8"],
  ["kube-system", "worker-1", "8", "16"] 
]
```

Enum.zip kinda works but I would have to first split the sub lists and I think there has to be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `Enum.reduce` for this one, converting the list to a map in the process.

The idea would be to "loop" over the list, each time updating an "accumulator" map with the sums, like this:

```elixir
[
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-25wv5", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-2nhbs", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-5b4dw", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-p7sx9", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],          
  ["coredns-autoscaler-76f8869cc9-gd69j", "kube-system", "worker-1", "1", "5"],
  ["coredns-55b58f978-q2skn", "kube-system", "worker-1", "7", "11"] 
]
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn [_, key, _, stat0, stat1], accumulator ->                                                   
  int0 = String.to_integer(stat0)
  int1 = String.to_integer(stat1)
  Map.update(accumulator, key, {int0, int1}, fn {x, y} -> {x + int0, y + int1} end)
end)
```

That would return:

```elixir
%{"kube-system" => {8, 16}, "nginx-deployment" => {0, 8}}
```

Note: I didn't include the "3rd" field because I'm not sure how that should be selected. Is it always going to be unique? Anyway, my answer outlines how I would approach this.

**Update:**

I've been working with Elixir ever since I wrote my original answer and I have come to appreciate using `reduce` in `for` expressions so I'm going to re-write my answer in what I think is a more readable format, for posterity.

This is called a "list comprehension".

```elixir
data = [
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-25wv5", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-2nhbs", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-5b4dw", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],
  ["nginx-66b6c48dd5-p7sx9", "nginx-deployment", "worker-1", "0", "2"],          
  ["coredns-autoscaler-76f8869cc9-gd69j", "kube-system", "worker-1", "1", "5"],
  ["coredns-55b58f978-q2skn", "kube-system", "worker-1", "7", "11"] 
]

for [_, key, _, stat0, stat1] <- data, reduce: %{} do
  accumulator ->                                                
    int0 = String.to_integer(stat0)
    int1 = String.to_integer(stat1)
    Map.update(accumulator, key, {int0, int1}, fn {x, y} -> {x + int0, y + int1} end)
end
```

Comment: The 3rd field might not be unique, so your solution works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the third field might be not unique, the solution by @PeacefulJames (which is otherwise absolutely correct,) might be too fragile due to hard-coded stuff. Here is more verbose, but better extendable solution, involving `Enum.group_by/3`.

```elixir
list
|> Enum.group_by(
  &Enum.slice(&1, 1..2),
  fn e ->
    e
    |> Enum.take(-2)
    |> Enum.map(&String.to_integer/1)
  end
) |> Enum.map(fn {k, v} ->
  k ++ Enum.reduce(v, [0, 0], fn [x, y], [xx, yy] -> [x + xx, y + yy] end) 
end)
  
#⇒ [["kube-system", "worker-1", 8, 16],
#   ["nginx-deployment", "worker-1", 0, 8]]
```